# MVC Core redirect to login after 5 minutes inactive

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, settimeout

I want to redirect the user to the login page after being inactive for 5 minutes.
I'm using MVC Core 3.1

Comment: How do you want to login? By Cookie authentication or Identity or any other ways?

Comment: We are using a 3rd party API to authenticate users

Answer (score 0):

> I want to redirect the user to the login page after being inactive for 5 minutes

If you use Cookie Authentication, you can specify the `ExpiresUtc` property to set the time at which the authentication ticket expires. Then use js to judge if user is inactive for 5 minutes, afterwards reload the page. At that time the cookie has been expired and it will redirect to the login page when reload the page.

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

1.AccountController:

```
[HttpGet]   
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    return View();  //render the login page
}  
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
{
     var claims = new List<Claim>
     { 
          new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,model.Name),
          new Claim("Password",model.Password)
     };
     var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
     await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), new AuthenticationProperties
           {
               ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),//set valid period of cookie
               IsPersistent = false,
               AllowRefresh = false
            });
      return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
```

2.HomeController:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

When you send request to `/Home/Index`, it will redirect to `/Account/Login` page and you need enter the name and password to login.

3.In the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method, create the Authentication Middleware services with the `AddAuthentication` and `AddCookie` methods:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

   .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, m =>
   {
     m.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";    //specify the login url
     m.AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("");
     m.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
}
```

4.In `Startup.Configure`, call the `UseAuthentication` and `UseAuthorization` methods before calling `UseEndpoints`:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

5.Set the refresh time in authorized page(Home/Index.cshtml):

```
@section Scripts{
<script >
    window.document.onmouseover = function () { oldTime = new Date().getTime(); }
    var oldTime = new Date().getTime();
    var currentTime;
    var timeOut = 300000;//refresh time
    $(function () {
        $(document).mouseover(function () {
            oldTime = new Date().getTime();
        });
    });
    function refresh() {
        currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        if (currentTime - oldTime > timeOut) {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
    window.setInterval(refresh,1000)
</script>
}
```

If your application contains many authorized pages, you can move the js code to external js file and add the reference to the authorized page.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I'll try it out